# Javascript -- any way to force a draw of new elements before processing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar, redraw

I have a javascript function or two that takes a few seconds to process.  I want to show an activity indicator so users don't think it's hung.  I tried bootstrap animated progress bars and spin.js -- the problem is, I put the code for them before the processing, but the browser doesn't seem to update to show the new elements until after the function has finished.  Obviously, an activity indicator that shows up after processing isn't incredibly useful.  Is there a way to force the redraw before the processing occurs?

EDIT: here's an example code.  This is from an HTA application, hence the pulling of files and such.  I know the forced "wait" portion is a bad idea, usually, but in this program, files are opened and closed immediately, this is to prevent a race conflict and I just want to give it a quick 10 retry timeout before it tells them something is wrong.  So, the problem is that this.spin() doesn't display its good until after the alert pops up.

```
Database.prototype.tryDatabase = function(fileName, toEdit, table, keepAlive) {
    if (typeof keepAlive === 'undefined') keepAlive = false;
    for (timeInd=0; timeInd < 5; timeInd++) {
        var complete = this._addToFile(fileName, toEdit, table, keepAlive);
        if (complete === false) {
            var until = moment().valueOf() + 2000;
            this.spin();
            while (moment().valueOf() <= until) {;}
        }
        else break;
    }
    if (complete === false) window.alert("Database was locked for an extended period, please try again");
    else if (!keepAlive) $('#added_to_db_modal').modal('show');
    return complete;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I added it.  I was avoiding posting the section I was working on because I wanted to get answers instead of people telling me the forced wait was a bad idea ;)

Comment: There's no code that would lead me to believe it is showing a progress bar. You should really redo this whole thing. I mean, not to sound harsh, but you realize you're blocking the run time with a while loop, right? I mean, I've never even heard of someone doing that. No user input will be taken into account until after the while loop ends. But anyway, add your code to show the progress bar before you send the request. And then hide it after.

Comment: The progress bar is the call to this.spin().

Comment: As I mentioned in the code, I'm doing the hanging of the computer for a specific reason.  This is an HTA application and it's just retrying to write to the database if someone else is using it at that second.  The hanging just tried a few times and then times out.  I didn't want it to asynchronously timeout for various reasons that can't be changed in the rest of the code.